# Segmentation fault in a program that uses scanf

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have problem with assembly program on my VirtualBox.
On VB I have Linux Mint(64 bit). I tried to compile this assembler code(in file `my_file.asm`):

```
extern printf  
extern scanf  

section .data  
format: db "%d",0  
napis: db "a/b=%d",10,0  

section .bss  
a: resd 1  
b: resd 1  

global main  
section .text  
main:  

mov rdi, format  
mov rsi, a  
xor rax, rax  
call scanf  

mov rdi, format  
mov rsi, b  
xor rax, rax  
call scanf  

mov eax, [a]  
xor edx, edx  
div dword[b]  

ret
```

At first I type: `nasm -f elf64 myfile.asm`
Then I type: `gcc myfile.o -o myfile`
And after this i have this error message:
 "/usr/bin/ld: plik.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against .bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
"

So i add `-no-pie` to gcc command: `gcc -o test test.o -no-pie`

**Now, when I use `./my_file` I have this error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and I don't know what to do.**

Comment: Looks about right except for not maintaining stack alignment. Put `sub rsp, 8` at `main` and `add rsp, 8` before the `ret`. Also, use a debugger to see where the crash is.

Comment: @lurker this is not a standalone program. It has `main` and it's linked to libc.

Comment: Not related to your segfault(I think Jester covers that with his stack alignment comment). If you wanted a position independent version of the NASM code without requiring `-no-pie` you can add `default rel` directive to the beginning of your ASM file and then change `call scanf` to `call scanf wrt ..plt` (there is a space between `wrt` and the `..`)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: they'd also need `default rel` for PIE, otherwise `[a]` will be an absolute `[disp32]` addressing mode.  PIE does allow 64-bit absolute addresses, though, so `mov rdi, format` is just inefficient, not an actual error.  (Because NASM chooses to assemble that to `mov r64, imm64`, unlike YASM which chooses `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : Pretty sure I said they'd have to add `default rel` to their ASM file.  From my comment: _"you can add `default rel` directive to the beginning of your ASM file and then "..._

Comment: @MichaelPetch: IDK how I missed that, sorry.